# AVFoundation max render size

Tags: ios, video, rendering, avfoundation

I've searched quite a lot and it seems that couldn't find a definite answer to what is the maximum render size of a video on iOS using `AVFoundation`.

I need to stitch two or more videos side by side or above each and render them in one new video with a final size larger than 1920 x 1080. So for example if I have two full hd videos (1920 x 1080) side by side the final composition would be 3840 x 1080.

I've tried with `AVAssetExportSession` and it always shrinks the final video proportionally to max 1920 in width or 1080 in height. It's quite understandable because of all possible `AVAssetExportSession` settings like preset, file type etc.

I tried also using `AVAssetReader` and `AVAssetWriter` but the results are the same. I only have more control over the quality, bitrate etc.

So.. is there a way this can be achieved on iOS or we have to stick to max Full HD?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well... Actually the answer should be **YES** and also **NO**. At least of what I've found until now.

H.264 allows higher resolutions only using a higher level profile which is fine. However on iOS the max profile that can be used is `AVVideoProfileLevelH264High41` which according the specs, permits a max resolution of **1,920×1,080@30.1 fps** or **2,048×1,024@30.0 fps**.
So encoding with H.264 won't do the job and the answer should be **NO**.

The other option is to use other compression/codec. I've tried `AVVideoCodecJPEG` and was able to render such a video. So the answer should be **YES**.
But.. the problem is that this video is not playable on iOS which again changes the answer to **NO**.

To summarise I'd say: it is possible if that video is meant to be used out of the device otherwise the video will simply not be useable.

Hope it will help other people as well and if someone else gives a better, even different answer I'll be glad.

Comment: Why AVVideoCodecJPEG is unplayable on iOS?

Comment: where did you find this specifications ?